# optimize Select sub query using alias

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query that selects multiple values from the same table in sub query

```
SELECT ...,
(
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pts), 0)
    FROM grades 
    WHERE s.id = student 
) AS spts,
(
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(mat), 0)
    FROM grades 
    WHERE s.id = student
) AS smat,
(
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bio), 0)
    FROM grades 
    WHERE s.id = student
)AS sbio
FROM ...
```

its working perfectly now but i think it can be optimized into one sub query instead of 3.

**what i tried**

```
SELECT ...,
(
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pts), 0) AS spts, IFNULL(SUM(mat), 0) AS smat, IFNULL(SUM(bio), 0) AS sbio
    FROM grades
    WHERE s.id = student
)
FROM ...
```

but i keep getting the following **error**

> "message":SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**expected output**

```
{
"spts": "89",
"smat": "44",
"sbio": "45"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it using a `left join`:

```
SELECT ...,
       COALESCE(spts, 0) as spts,
       COALESCE(smat, 0) as smat,
       COALESCE(sbio, 0) as sbio
FROM ... LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT student, SUM(pts) AS spts, SUM(mat) AS smat, SUM(bio) AS sbio
      FROM grades
      GROUP BY student
     ) g
     ON s.id = g.student;
```

Depending on what else is in the `FROM` clause (and potentially `WHERE` clause), this may not speed up the query.

Comment: amazing solution but now i am getting the below error `"message":SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'g.student' in 'on clause'`